# How can I link to the root of the site with Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have this `ActionLink` to login:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

From the Home view, it works, resulting in this url:

```
http://localhost:12676/Account/Login
```

But then, when another area is accessed, the `ActionLink` results in this url:

```
http://localhost:12676/Admin/ManagerAccounts/Login/loginLink
```

What do I need to change to cause the `ActionLink` to always result in `~/Account/Login`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To force the ActionLink to be relative to the root of the site, and not the current Area, give it an empty string Area as a route value, otherwise it will try to use the current area in the route:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", routeValues: new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

Comment: It works but without routeValues:, I use this:         `@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })`

Comment: @user1911 THat's actually the same thing, just without naming the parameters. Named parameters are optional in C#.